# Ionic/Cordova: How to install plugin into existing project?

Tags: git, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

How do I install an additional Cordova plugin into an existing Ionic/Cordova project? I need the Cordova Camera Plugin. If I try:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

I get error:

```
Error: Command failed: fatal: could not create work tree dir .... No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121382/cant-install-cordova-plugins-from-git-on-cli

Comment: That helped fixing the install issue but how do I integrate the plugin API with Ionic? In my JS it now tells me that e.g. Camera is not defined. also FileUploadOptions and FileTransfer are marked as unresolved types.

Comment: Did you include cordova.js to your project? If you have, you should create a new issue for this as its not really related to this issue.

Comment: Since this is an Ionic Framework project cordova.js is internally managed by Ionic in some way. The file itself doesn't seem to be existing in the project structure. I'll open a new ticket!

Comment: Are you trying it in your browser or on the device ?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing the right thing but you have camera.git at the end.
That is the problem.
This is correct way of doing it! It worked for me.

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install cordova plugin in ionic by tapping these commands line :

```
$ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
$npm install --save @ionic-native/camera
```

Add the plugin in your module app [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module)

And follow the instruction on the official documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/

Good luck :)