# Ionic cordova Plugin install error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

*Firstly, let me premise this with the fact that I've looked at many similar posts on this site and others (links are provided below), and I've "tried" all of the suggested solutions, to no avail. And I honestly think the solutions aren't working for me simply because I don't really understand them. Please someone write a clear explanation of the problem and solution in **beginner/novice-approppriate-language**. PLEASE and MANY Thanks!*

**What I'm trying to do...**
Build a hybrid app in ionic.

**What I've done so far...** successfully installed ionic, cordova, & gulp (following the instructions at http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

**The Issue:**
After changing the directory to my project (C:/Users/[me]/$HOME/.node_modules_global/), I run the following command:

```
ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

and, although ionic runs fine, Cordova Plugins fail to add, and suggests it's a version issue, as shown in the below screenshot:

[image: What I get after running "ionic start myApp sidemenu"]

Now, as addressed in the following forums, the issue might be due to "Ownership changing" in root and tmp folder (wth does that even mean??). (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7281)

Can someone tell me exactly what to do? I don't understand the comments of the issue in that link, and I don't know how to go about fixing it.

I'm on Windows 8. and anytime I use "sudo" it won't recognize that as a command, or even "chown".

Same thing with these posts:

[Cordova version error while using ionic to create new app although cordova is latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982982/cordova-version-error-while-using-ionic-to-create-new-app-although-cordova-is-la)

[Ionic/Cordova: How to install plugin into existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671826/ionic-cordova-how-to-install-plugin-into-existing-project)

Comment: manually download the plugin and place it in the plugin folder

Comment: The plugin folder of cordova? which plugin folder are you talking about?  @CraZyDroiD

Comment: there should be a folder named plugins right below the folder named platforms

Comment: @CraZyDroiD, so, I'm assuming you mean the platform folder that should have been created in my ionic project "myApp"? There is no platforms folder there. I'm starting to get suspicious that I need to download all the SDKs first? If so, the Ionic documentation needs a serious upgrade because it doesn't mention that...

Comment: Have you tried starting the project right at the (C:/) ?. I think the problem is because of the environment dependency. If that still doesn't help. i recommend you to delete the path in the environment variables, delete the .ionic, .cordova just inside of the users folder. And, start over with the installation of ionic and cordova.

Answer (score 1):

please update your cordova CLI by using this command

> **npm update -g cordova**

For more details you check on https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/updating-apache-cordova-platform-latest-version/

Hopes this will help you.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't help. Thanks for reaching out tho. Updating will have little effect since I've been installing cordova within the last 48 hrs. In any case, I did try `npm update -g cordova` as you suggested, but the error persists when starting an ionic app

Comment: move into your project folder myApp and install the cordova plugin directly from their GitHub using the below command

 $ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Now you can add platforms and start to play with IONIC

Comment: Your issue is more similar with issues on ionic forum http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-add-plugins-perhaps-your-version-of-cordova-is-too-old/3807/34

Comment: so I moved into my project folder and ran: `$HOME\.node_modules_global\myApp>  cordova plugin add git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git  ` but got the error: `cordova is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.` so then I went up one level in my directory and tried again: `$HOME_.node_modules_global>cordova plugin add git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git  ` and get the result `Current working directory is not a cordova-based project`.

Comment: I'm totally confused as to where my cordova package, .node_modules_global, and ionic packages should be installed and where I can access the ionic and/or cordova commands. I've been trying to learn up on it, but every source I turn to is super confusing and vague D:

Comment: Santosh, Thanks for adding that link to the forum. I hadn't seen that one. Going to look at it and see if I'm able to fix anything.

Comment: more one related link with your issue https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/38

Comment: Not. I tried what "eminarslan" posted on that forum you sent me: I  included in the PATH field:

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;`

still no luck when running `ionic start myApp sidemenu`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75893/discussion-between-alexsandra-guerra-and-santosh-shinde).

Answer (score 0):

You can't run `sudo` or `chown` on your Windows. It's only support for `Linux` and `Macintosh`. What you can do now is `Run as Administrator` if you want to install the latest cordova plugin on your `Windows`.

Comment: do you mean run the command: 'Run As Administrator' in the cmd? I tried that and it says "Run is not recognized as an internal or external command". (I also tried with with lowercase 'run')

Comment: Oh, I see. So, I just tried that- cmd (Run as Administrator). then `npm install -g cordova`. installed okay. then `cd [appDirectory]`, then `ionic start myApp sidemenu`, and I get the same error message as shown in my picture above

Comment: Ok, just did that. still no luck. Error persists

Comment: manually download the plugin and place it in the plugin folder